# Jquery fullscreen

Tags: jquery, html

I am using this piece of JS from http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen

```
<script> 
// Find the right method, call on correct element
function launchFullscreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}


  var form = $("#my-id");
  $("#my-button").click(function () {
  // Launch fullscreen for browsers that support it!
  launchFullScreen(document.documentElement); // the whole page
  form.submit();
  });

</script>
```

setting up the handler for the click event as above,
the HTML is as below

```
<form id="my-id" class="form" action="/nextpage" method="post" name="my-name"> 
    <button id="my-button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> OK Fullscreen </button>   
</form>
```

The form submits alright but not through the handler I write in the script section, why and how do I fix this?

Comment: `Through handler`?? you can not do this through handler

Comment: why not can you elaborate?

Comment: Handler will not put code into your browser you can use it only

Comment: ok I am clearly not understanding what you are saying, the code is obviously loaded into the browser and on the button click it does not go through the script written above which I am testing through breakpoints. Do you see something wrong with my expectations here?

Comment: which api you are using?